# PHP Search Engine

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have put together a very complicated search form. Using arrays I have managed to get it searching by checkboxes.

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){
foreach($_POST['search'] as $key=>$value){
    if($value==1) $search[] = "$key";
}
$searchstring = implode(' AND ', $search);
```

}

```
        $query = "SELECT candidate_id.master_id, candidate_contact_details.first_name, candidate_contact_details.last_name, candidate_contact_details.home_phone, candidate_contact_details.work_phone, candidate_contact_details.mobile_phone, candidate_contact_details.email FROM candidate_id, candidate_contact_details, qualifications, security_experience, previous_career WHERE qualifications.active = 'finished' and candidate_id.master_id = candidate_contact_details.c_id and candidate_id.master_id = qualifications.c_id and $searchstring";
```

I know how to do searches of the database by a specific term. ie. postcode field but does anyone know how I can add that to this query? I know how to do either checkbox based searches or text field based searches but cannot figue out how to combine the two.

Thanks Again
Jason

Comment: Makes sense this does not. Searching by checkboxes you are? (sry Star Wars Ep. 3 last night)

Comment: Complicated? You aint seen nothin...

Comment: You might want to look up what SQL injection means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question, you need to map the names of the form fields to database columns. You could set up an array like:

```
$post_map = array(
    'home_phone' => 'candidate_contact_details.home_phone',
    'first_name' => 'candidate_contact_details.first_name',
    // etc.
  );
```

Then you could add things to your query like (just an untested example...):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  if (array_key_exists($key, $post_map))
  {
     $search[] = $post_map[$key] . '=' . mysql_real_escape_string($value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I see where you are going with this. I am fairly new to php so this is a learning exercise. Not a production enviroment. As far as I can tell by what you have said the map will allow me to add these to my array am I right?

Comment: @Jason Gearhart In the example code I am adding fields and their values to the `$search` array, complete entries like for example `candidate_contact_details.home_phone=mysql_real_escape_string("12345678")` when you put `12345678` in the form field `home_phone`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. Just trying to figure out where it goes in my code.

Comment: @Jason Gearhart I guess that you would use `$_POST['search']` where I use `$_POST` as you have all your search fields in an array inside the POST array.

Comment: Ok. shows a syntax error at the line:      $search[] = $post_map[$key] . '=' . mysql_real_escape_string($value);

Comment: @Jason Gearhart You need to have a database connection open to use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Will check it on the php server and advise.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am sure the syntax errors are myfault. Will be a good excerise for me to find them.

Comment: found it. ) was missing fom the end os the if statment

Comment: no problem. Code now does not have a syntax error but having probs getting it to return a result. Hope to come back with some positive news soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
SELECT 
    candidate_id.master_id, candidate_contact_details.first_name, candidate_contact_details.last_name, candidate_contact_details.home_phone, candidate_contact_details.work_phone, candidate_contact_details.mobile_phone, candidate_contact_details.email FROM candidate_id, candidate_contact_details, qualifications, security_experience, previous_career 
WHERE 
    (qualifications.active = 'finished' and candidate_id.master_id = candidate_contact_details.c_id and candidate_id.master_id = qualifications.c_id) and $searchstring";
```

additionally, 
didn't you want " OR " instead of " AND "?

Comment: it is an AND as in there are about 50 checkboxes and any combination of these needs to be selected. ie. in the qualifications table the search may be anyone with alevel and degree but not olevel and such.